# How to post to on facebook user wall as the user in PHP

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I find tutorials to post in a user own wall through a web app in php but there are using `publish_stream`, `publish_actions`, `offline_access` that are all deprecated, so is it still possible to do that and how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, (un)fortunately this functionality was removed some time ago.